# Jenkins build success but failed on Unit test

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins

I am having issue resolving Jenkins unit test fail with following error: "testException = java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<> but was:<>" Jenkins build was success with Unit test fail. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you give some more details about your jenkins job?
I believe you need to publish the junit test results to alter the build status.

E.g. If you are using a jenkinsfile for your configuration

```
// publish JUnit results to Jenkins
step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/build/test-results/*.xml'])
```

If you are using the ui configuration for the job there is a field where you can configure this.

Comment: Hi @Kirsteen, Thanks for your response. Jenkins actually publishing the junit results and I am getting only one error out of 300 tests.

Comment: you can say that. However, I don't understand how would publishing the junit test results in Jenkins would resolve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue after creating Free Style project instead of Maven project. Not sure why Maven project for my maven project gives false positive.